# Why was the selected answer changed after two years?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, unaccepted-answer

[In linq how dynamically pass table and column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222082/in-linq-how-dynamically-pass-table-and-column-name/3224759#3224759)

Two years ago, my answer was selected.  Today, I get a -15 with no comment, and no indication of a user action.

I don't know who did what.

This is very discouraging.

Comment: On closer examination, OP has asked a follow-up question in comments on the newly accepted answer.  sigh.

Comment: With 40k rep, I think you can afford a -15.

Comment: follow-up question that invalidates an accepted answer. Hmm that pretty much sounds like one of [“chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) kind

Comment: Why is this "very discouraging?"

Comment: @JohnDibling I had no feedback for the -15.  I could not tell if it was a community edit.  Much of my rep is in accepted answers and it is discouraging that I might lose all of that with no explanation.  The answers on this meta have helped me be less discouraged.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The OP can change their mind at any time, and unaccept an accepted answer.

Unless the question asker leaves a comment as to why your answer was now unaccepted, there is no way to know their motivations.

In this case, they must have come back to the question much later, and after exchanging some comments with the other answerer, decided to mark the other answer as more helpful instead.

Bad luck for you, but there isn't anything that can be done about this!

Answer (score 3):

The OP must have simply thought that the newly selected answer was more helpful/correct to him than yours. By whatever definition this might have been decided we can't know.

Though looking at the answer, several recent comments indicate a recent interaction with the author of the now accepted answer. This might have triggered the decision to change the accepted answer on account of helpfulness. Though that's mere speculation.

Answer (score 2):

And what do you expect now?

A user can unmark an answer as accepted any time he wants. If OP thinks the answer is not correct or he wants to choose another one as accepted because in the end it helped him/her more, then this is totally the choice of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

The OP may have done this for a variety of reasons. For instance, they may have decided that the other answer is a better implementation, or when looking at their posts, just decided to accept another answer. There really is no way to get them to accept your answer again, and there is no need to worry. Your rep isnt going to be gone anytime soon.